# Show who has flagged you

Tags: views, flags

I have a content view of user images. They have a 'flag user' flag attached to them. I suppose it all works just the same if I had the user flag in the user page.

I wanted to create a block view (or page) that shows who has flagged a logged-in user when that user is viewing their own profile.

I have tried every relationship under the sun. I alwasy seem to end up of a list of users the logged-in user has flagged, not the other way around.

Could anyone help put me out my misery?

I am using the latest releases of the Views and Flags modules.

Comment: Hello. Could you provide name and link to a module you are using to flag? If it exposes it's data to views the right way, it should be easy to just add relationships like content author -> content -> flag author to a view. Tried that? What failed?

Comment: Thanks Molot. Im using the latest .3 version of th Flag module. Ive tried loads of relationships Molot :(

Comment: Give us sql query that generated by views. Obviously, you've made a mistake in relationships.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. Sorry ive been away for a few days. I cant seem to get the SQL results but here is a picture of my view http://s15.postimg.org/8lxmhi6d7/flagggs.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with a contextual filter with Flags: content ID, and then take the default value of type 'User ID from logged in user'.

It worked for me.